# How can I fetch value from xml in Spring Boot Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

My xml contains

```
<List><came cameId="cam-1" cameName="Came 1"></List>
```

How can I fetch cameid in Java class?

Comment: Incidentally, there is no `camid` in your XML. There is a `cameId` - XML is case sensitive and you've misspelled your requirement in your question.

Comment: created a cam class in which I used setter and getter and another class I called the cam class as  "cams" so now how to fetch value or atleast to print camid in Sysop

Comment: Create an xsd for the xml, generate JAXB classes from it, then call `getCame().getCameId()` on the unmarshalled `List`.

Comment: @MattJones see the updated

Comment: XML is case sensitive. If you cannot use consistent casing in your question, you should be even more careful in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XStream](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/1.4.5) jar
write the code like this

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
(java object name) xstream.fromXML(new ClassPathResource("location of your xml file ").getFile());
```

variable name should be same in both java object and xml file.